# Discounted prices disapper for some time

Tags: magento-1.9

i have problem with catalog price rules in magento 1.9.1. 
We have some products on which we are applying catalog price rule to give the discount. Applied catalog price rules are working fine initially.

But for some time it disappears in a day and customers are unable to get discount at that time. When customer add the product to his cart then full price of product is showing in his cart instead of showing discounted price.

The discounted prices appear again after sometime,that there is some delay and that causes inconvenience to the customers who are trying to buy products.

We checked the above scenario on our test server but unable to replicate the issue. 
How can we replicate this issue on our test server and fix it ?